# Improving Reliability of WebClient

Tags: c#, http, webclient

I have written a simple API for controlling a piece of hardware via http commands. ~ 85% of the time this all works fine but occasionally my hardware does not respond to the commands, the request times out and I get a WebException thrown. My question is what other actions could I take to improve the reliability of the connection, here is the code I have written for sending the command:

```
private String SendCommand(String command)
    {
        String response;

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.Proxy = null;
                response = client.DownloadString(command);
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                new WebException("Couldn't connect to power unit at " + _ipAddress);
                throw;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

My hardware is connected to a dedicated NIC and I have a fixed IP address specified for the NIC and the hardware in the 169.254.103.X range. Would specifying a default gateway or a different subnet mask for this connection improve the situation? I have tried playing around with these settings but it seems to have little impact, but then I don't have a lot of experience or knowledge in http or networking so might not be making the right changes.

Comment: Using a 169.254.x.x IP address is an oddity. That's usually reserved for auto-configuration when DHCP fails. I would ponder if your device is periodically re-attempting to get a DHCP address and momentarily drops the 169.254.x.x address. In any case, I would doubt your WebClient is your problem if you are getting a ~15% failure rate.